# Summing up duplicate properties' values into a new object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to sum up values that appear in an array of objects that is constructed like this:

```
[ 
  { token: 'N97235', conversions: '2', payout: '100' },
  { token: 'N91567', conversions: '2', payout: '100' },
  { token: 'N91567', conversions: '3', payout: '150' },
  { token: 'N97759', conversions: '2', payout: '100' },
  { token: 'N97240', conversions: '1', payout: '50' },
  { token: 'N13925', conversions: '1', payout: '50' },
  { token: 'N53285', conversions: '1', payout: '50' },
  { token: 'N28312', conversions: '1', payout: '100' },
  { token: 'N96475', conversions: '1', payout: '50' },
  { token: 'N97759', conversions: '2', payout: '100' },
  { token: 'N76951', conversions: '1', payout: '100' },
  { token: 'N39108', conversions: '1', payout: '50' },
  { token: 'N39108', conversions: '4', payout: '200' },
  { token: 'N48854', conversions: '2', payout: '100' },
  { token: 'N50179', conversions: '1', payout: '50' },
  { token: 'N18804', conversions: '1', payout: '50' },
  { token: 'N95631', conversions: '2', payout: '100' },
]
```

What I mean is that i want to sum all the conversions and payouts into a new object that looks like this

```
{
  N97235: { conversions: 2, payout: 100 },
  N39108: { conversions: 5, payout: 250 },
  N91567: { conversions: 6, payout: 300},
  N96475: { conversions: 1, payout: 50},
  // ..and so on
}
```

As you can see, it found the duplicate 'entries' in the original array and summed their conversions and payouts into a new object (single entries go there as well with).
What I tried to do is to go over this array (tokens_array[] in this case) and attach its' objects properties to the new created object (the conversions_sum{} one), but the problem is 'nullifying' its' values first, before adding anything to them..

```
tokens_array.forEach(function(element) {
    var token_string = element.token.toString();
    conversions_sum[token_string] = {};
    conversions_sum[token_string].conversions += element.conversions;
    conversions_sum[token_string].payout += element.payout;
});
```

But since *conversions_sum[token_string].conversions* and *conversions_sum[token_string].payout* weren't initialised from the first place - it adds the number to 'undefined'..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create the hash object of the tokens like this:

```js
function group(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(h, e) {             // for each object e in arr
    if(h[e.token]) {                             // if we already hashed the object
      h[e.token].conversions += +e.conversions;  // add e's conversions to the hashed object (implicitly convert e.conversions into a number using unary +)
      h[e.token].payout += +e.payout;            // add e's payout to the hashed object as well
    }                                            
    else {                                       // if not, then create a new object initialized with e's values
      h[e.token] = {conversions: +e.conversions, payout: +e.payout};
    }

    return h;
  }, {});
}

var array = [ 
  { token: 'N97235', conversions: '2', payout: '100' },
  { token: 'N91567', conversions: '2', payout: '100' },
  { token: 'N91567', conversions: '3', payout: '150' },
  { token: 'N97759', conversions: '2', payout: '100' },
  { token: 'N97240', conversions: '1', payout: '50' },
  { token: 'N13925', conversions: '1', payout: '50' },
  { token: 'N53285', conversions: '1', payout: '50' },
  { token: 'N28312', conversions: '1', payout: '100' },
  { token: 'N96475', conversions: '1', payout: '50' },
  { token: 'N97759', conversions: '2', payout: '100' },
  { token: 'N76951', conversions: '1', payout: '100' },
  { token: 'N39108', conversions: '1', payout: '50' },
  { token: 'N39108', conversions: '4', payout: '200' },
  { token: 'N48854', conversions: '2', payout: '100' },
  { token: 'N50179', conversions: '1', payout: '50' },
  { token: 'N18804', conversions: '1', payout: '50' },
  { token: 'N95631', conversions: '2', payout: '100' },
];

console.log(group(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

So then, initialize them, right? You're also overwriting your new object everytime, but you only want to when it doesn't exist. Like So:

```
 conversions_sum[token_string] = conversions_sum[token_string] || {
   conversions: 0,
   payout: 0
 };
conversions_sum[token_string].conversions += parseInt(element.conversions, 10);
conversions_sum[token_string].payout += parseInt(element.payout, 10);
```

Comment: It works great, but i'm not sure i fully understood how this mechanism fully works in this line -
  
      conversions_sum[token_string] = conversions_sum[token_string] || {
      conversions: 0,
      payout: 0
    };

When there -is- a token_string found - so it just makes it equal to itself? I mean, 

    a = a || { k: 3, r: 4}

What exactly it does when a is being equaled to a?

Comment: Yup, it's just shorthand using `||` since you only want to initialize a new object for a key when it doesn't exist, so assigning it to itself does what? That's right, it does nothing. I was merely trying to help you with your existing code example to help you understand rather than rewrite your entire logic like Mr Ibrahim did.